# RMarkdown not compiling into PDF

Tags: r, pdf, compilation, r-markdown

I need to use RMarkdown to compile into one pdf but its not working. All my scripts work perfectly on their own but dont want to create the pdf in RMarkdown. What do I need to do, I don't use RMarkdown enough to know what to do.

Here is my error output:

```
output file: R-Markdown-Midterm.knit.md

A new version of TeX Live has been released. If you need to install or update any LaTeX packages, you have to upgrade TinyTeX with tinytex::reinstall_tinytex(). If it fails to upgrade, you might be using a default random CTAN mirror that has not been fully synced to the main CTAN repository, and you need to wait for a few more days or use a CTAN mirror that is known to be up-to-date (see the "repository" argument on the help page ?tinytex::install_tinytex()).

tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2020).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
! LaTeX Error: File `xcolor.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile R-Markdown-Midterm.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See R-Markdown-Midterm.log for more info.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In in_dir(input_dir(), evaluate(code, envir = env, new_device = FALSE,  :
  You changed the working directory to /Users/eruiz/Desktop/Stevens/Summer 2020/FE630 Portfolio Theory and Applications/Midterm/Summer 2020/Code (probably via setwd()). It will be restored to /Users/eruiz/Desktop/Stevens/Summer 2020/FE630 Portfolio Theory and Applications/Midterm/Summer 2020. See the Note section in ?knitr::knit
2: In in_dir(input_dir(), evaluate(code, envir = env, new_device = FALSE,  :
  You changed the working directory to /Users/eruiz/Desktop/Stevens/Summer 2020/FE630 Portfolio Theory and Applications/Midterm/Summer 2020/Code (probably via setwd()). It will be restored to /Users/eruiz/Desktop/Stevens/Summer 2020/FE630 Portfolio Theory and Applications/Midterm/Summer 2020. See the Note section in ?knitr::knit
3: In system2("tlmgr", args, ...) :
  running command ''tlmgr' search --file --global '/xcolor.sty'' had status 1
Execution halted
```

Comment: Maybe, one of the equations in your document did not have `$`

Comment: Its unlikely because I've ran everything multiple times and it works perfectly. All the outputs work in RMarkdown too but only when I compile into a pdf do I have issues

Comment: https://community.rstudio.com/t/file-xcolor-sty-not-found/30028/6

Comment: @rawr I agree its probably due to ``xcolor.sty`` but I have tinytex updated so I don't know what's the issue

Comment: Maybe try a different latex engine, like mikTeX

Comment: @Duck I unfortunately don't know how to do that. I did ``tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()`` and that fixed the original error but now I get ``! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character β (U+03B2)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

Try other LaTeX engines instead (e.g., xelatex) if you are using pdflatex. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-unicode.html``

Comment: You have to install `inputenc` in your original tinytex distribution. They have package manager. Then, it will work.